# Secure boot on with no system

Tags: fastboot, boot-loop, bootloader

I have bought a cellphone (google nexus 5) and can only boot to bootloader, recovery seems erased since it will only reboot, same for system.
I cannot flash anything since get_unlock_ability returns 0.
Any way out of this ?

Comment: Sounds like someone locked the bootloader without recovery installed... which shouldn't normally be possible... or the emmc storage is bad (common in these older Nexus 4/5 models)... Most likely a brick if you can't flash anything or run recovery directly with `fastboot boot recovery.img` and you can't unlock it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the issue is that with a locked bootloader I get:
Sending 'boot.img' (17893 KB)                      OKAY [  0.517s]
Booting                                            FAILED (remote: 'unlock device to use this command')

I read we had to remove secure boot from the options, which is not possible in my case.
I saw it booting in it's constant reboot loop, I mean on system. But screen was frozen. I'll have to leave it aside waiting for a proper boot to flash everything back.

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky enough to find a working system to remove secure boot after I carefully folllowed the instruction to remove the battery.